# How to change the Networks of the Duals Sim?

Tags: android

am having the dual sim phone . In Application i want change the the dual sim networks such as GSM and LTE .  i captured the logs and got the activity name of com.android.phone.mMobileNetwork . but when i see in source code it is not avalable.

Please suggest me in proper manner that how to change the networks in dual sim including the both SIM's /

Thank sin advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't.
[See answer from hackbod (Google android developer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255147/dual-sim-card-android)

Android SDK does not support dual sim, and manufacturers are not willing to give out the source (nor to write a dialer which supports phone number based sim selection).