# send sms with second sim card by android on samsung duos

Tags: android, sms

I want to send sms by sim 1 or 2 programtically, relevant to recieved sms by samsung duos .
but the answer to the `stackoverflow` question [Dual SIM card Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255147/dual-sim-card-android) is that android unable to do so. Is there any other solution to do this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering here with respect to Samsung specifically, since the general question has been answered already. Android developers usually respond to such queries by stating that you should contact the hardware developer to see if they have created a specialised API to deal with dual SIMs.  In the case of Samsung, the company's reply to such a question is [here](http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=GeneralB&messageId=154434&startPage=86&curPage=88); unfortunately, they clearly state that they are not providing any additional API (at least as of 2012, and there has been no announcement of any change since).

So the effective answer is that you can't do this, except perhaps with [Java reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517338/android-check-whether-the-phone-is-dual-sim), which may or may not yield the names of the method calls that Samsung itself uses for this purpose.