# How to send sms from specific SIM card in dual phone

Tags: android, sms, dual-sim

I have trying to develop an android app which sending SMS to target.
if there are two SIM (SIM1, SIM2) card how can I detect them and select specific SIM card to send SMS
Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dual SIM card Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255147/dual-sim-card-android)

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255147/dual-sim-card-android) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19557147/send-sms-with-second-sim-card-by-android-on-samsung-duos)

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code. using Android sdk 5.1 and above.

```
String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

PendingIntent localPendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, new Intent(this.SENT), 0);
PendingIntent localPendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, new Intent(this.DELIVERED), 0);

SubscriptionManager localSubscriptionManager = SubscriptionManager.from(mContext);
if (localSubscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoCount() > 1)
{
List localList = localSubscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();
final String[] arrayOfString = new String[localList.size()];
int i = 0;
Iterator localIterator = localList.iterator();
while (localIterator.hasNext())
{
SubscriptionInfo localSubscriptionInfo = (SubscriptionInfo)localIterator.next();
localSubscriptionInfo.getSubscriptionId();
//log.d("22 api level ", "got dual sim: ");
int j = i + 1;
arrayOfString[i] = (localSubscriptionInfo.getCarrierName().toString() + " " + localSubscriptionInfo.getNumber());
i = j;
}

SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(paramString1, null, paramString2, localPendingIntent1, localPendingIntent2);
```

Comment: refer this link also..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093754/send-sms-using-sim-selection-option#

Comment: The question is asking **how to send SMS from specific SIM**  not to get info about specific SIM!

Answer (score -1):

**in MTK platform you can use :**

```
SmsManagerEx.getDefault().sendTextMessage(serverAddress, null,
                    textMessage, pendingIntent, null, mSIM);
```