# How to check the numbers of SIM in android device

Tags: android, imei

I am creating a application in which i have to send the IMEI (International Mobile Equipment Identity) number to the server, IMEI is a unique 15-digit serial number. This is to register the device on the server that unique number on the server and then fetch all the details of that device and send it to the server like, call details,wifi,mac address ,messages,contacts e.t.c

How can i fetch both the sims details when there are two SIMs in the device, and there details of both the sims like mobile numbers, call details/history,messages,contacts of both the SIMs separately.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TelephonyInfo` to get details of the dual sim phone.

for better explanation, have a look at this post.

[Android : Check whether the phone is dual SIM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17499889/1626878)

Comment: i think Android does not support dual SIMs in their OS's.

Comment: You knew that, still you posted the question? I have never came around such a situation. but I have found this post only that might help.

Comment: There are plenty of Android phones that support dual SIM!

Comment: @sahil thanks for the suggestion, i have check this link only after posting the problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255147/dual-sim-card-android and after implemetation i got telephonyInfo.getImeiSIM2() returns null, but device have dual sim and both are active.

Comment: The post you are referring to is of **March 2011**. Since then there are lots of enhancements in android system.

Comment: Also I think the Device manufacturer could provide with some API's that could work for dual sim devices.

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj it feels awkward when u posted 'You knew that, still you posted the question?' .... Is it right way to respond !!!

Comment: @ManishYadav Ohh, was it rude? I did'nt mean it that way. I was just amazed that you were making that statement just after posting a question on it.