# How can i send sms from my application

Tags: android, android-intent

This is working but sending sms from **sim1** only, i want to send from **sim2**.

```
String num = number.getText().toString();
String uri = "geo:" + gps.getLatitude() + "," + gps.getLongitude();
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(num, null, uri, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible through android api, for details check the following answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5255993/4349688

Answer (score -1):

It seems to be possible!

Use this link to get slot ids: [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517338/android-check-whether-the-phone-is-dual-sim?rq=1)

and use this link to send SMS by using a specific slot id: [link 2](http://labs.mediatek.com/site/global/developer_tools/mediatek_android/api_references/mediatek-sdk3/reference/com/mediatek/telephony/SmsManagerEx.gsp)