# IMEI number issue: IMEI number is changing using code

Tags: android

I am using a **dual Sim phone** And sometimes I get different IMEI numbers using the following code:

```
TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager)     
MyApplication.getInstance().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String imeiNumber = manager.getDeviceId();
```

How to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255147/dual-sim-card-android), device manufacturers modify Android to support dual SIMs. However, you can use [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517338/android-check-whether-the-phone-is-dual-sim/17499889#17499889) to get the details of both SIMs.